# MySQL select and group by with concat

Tags: sql, mysql, join, group

I have 2 table:

properties:

```
id,name
10,Weight
11,Color
12,Width
13,Height
```

product_prop:

```
id,product,prop,name
1,171243,10,12.56
2,171243,11,white
3,171243,12,500
4,127865,10,10.01
5,127865,11,white
```

My query:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name AS propName,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT pp.name SEPARATOR ',') AS propValue,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT pp.id SEPARATOR ',') AS propKey
FROM properties p 
INNER JOIN product_prop pp ON p.id = pp.prop
WHERE pp.product in (171243, 127865)
GROUP BY p.id, p.name;
```

The result:

| id | propName | propValue | propKey |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | Weight | 12.56,10.01 | 1,4 |
| 11 | Color | white | 2,5 |
| 12 | Width | 500 | 3 |

The first and last row its ok.
The 2nd row propKey i can see the only first found (2), because the 5 its equal the 2 (with name in product_prop table).

Comment: If you don't want distinct, you can remove `distinct` from your `group_concat` function?

Comment: What's you're desired result?

Comment: @Equinox:
Without distinct, the 2nd row is 11|color|white,white|2,5

Comment: @RobEyre
1st and 3rd row its ok, the 2nd row: 11|Color|white|2

Comment: Maybe `MIN` instead of `GROUP_CONCAT`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you could do this with a subselect that first identifies unique property values per property, then an outer select that does your aggregation:

```sql
SELECT
    p.id, p.name AS propName,
    GROUP_CONCAT(upp.propValue) AS propValue,
    GROUP_CONCAT(upp.propKey) AS propKey
FROM properties p
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        pp.prop,
        pp.name AS propValue,
        MIN(pp.id) AS propKey
    FROM product_prop pp
    WHERE pp.product in (171243, 127865)
    GROUP BY pp.prop, pp.name
) upp ON p.id = upp.prop
GROUP BY p.id, p.name;
```